# Opening new window with button in OpenERP

Tags: button, odoo

Firstly, i want to create a form in `OpenERP`with a button on it. When that button clicked, that button will link to the **project.issue** form.
What should be written on the button to perform such task?
I'm using developers mode on `OpenERP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One point to note, in the window action you return you can add a "target" value.  This is similar to HTML - "current" will open the form in the existing window, "new" will do it as a modal popup.

Answer (score 3):

Call this method from xml file, through button,like

```
       <button name="method_name" string="Open Form" type="object">


       def method_name(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
           """Method is used to show form view in new windows"""
          view_ref = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'module_name', 'form_view_id')
          view_id = view_ref and view_ref[1] or False,
          this = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0]
          return {
               'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
               'name': 'Form heading',
               'view_mode': 'form',
               'view_type': 'form',
               'view_id': view_id,
               'res_model': 'module.name',
               'nodestroy': True,
               'res_id': this.id, # assuming the many2one
               'target':'new',
               'context': context,
    }
```

where: form_view_id, which view u want to show...
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write some thing like this.

```
def open_sale_order_lines(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        sale_ids = self.pool.get('sale.order').search(cr,uid,[('project_id','=',context.get('search_default_project_id',False)),('partner_id','in',context.get('search_default_partner_id',False))])
        names = [record.name for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)]
        name = _('Sales Order Lines of %s') % ','.join(names)
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'name': name,
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'context': context,
            'domain' : [('order_id','in',sale_ids)],
            'res_model': 'sale.order.line',
            'nodestroy': True,
}
```